# Class 'KeenIO\Client\KeenIOClient' not found

Tags: keen-io

I am including Keen in my product (code snippet below)

```
    require INCLUDE_DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php';   // Autoloader for Composer (https://getcomposer.org/)
    use KeenIO\Client\KeenIOClient;

    class Statistics extends Model {

        private $client;

        public function __construct( $id = null ){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->client = KeenIOClient::factory([
                'projectId' => KEEN_PROJECT_ID,
                'writeKey'  => KEEN_WRITE_KEY,
                'readKey'   => KEEN_READ_KEY
            ]);
        }
...
```

but I continue to get an "Class 'KeenIO\Client\KeenIOClient' not found" error when the "KeenIOClient::factory" line runs. I was able to successfully install Keen.io through Composer - I feel it's something simple I'm missing - any ideas?

Comment: How did you install the Keen Client? Composer? If so, can you confirm that the Keen files exist in your `/vendor` folder? Updating the question with your composer.json may be helpful.

Comment: Hi, @jwegner. I successfully installed the Keen PHP Client through Composer. I can confirm that the "keen-io" folder exists under /vendor. Lastly my composer.json is as follows: `{
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0",
        "keen-io/keen-io": "~2.5",
 "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "~6.0"
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I can't leave a comment, but I am wondering if there is maybe an issue with the include path? I was able to get this PHP snippet to work:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use KeenIO\Client\KeenIOClient;

$client = KeenIOClient::factory([
  'projectId' => "53f3a8687d8cb95095000001",
  'readKey' => "99a06e48fd7fb1279bc40995160eb0b61a9e0efaab8b651b029f0d895f77c0a804ba089282eff28bf8ad07f337422441d0542b7feaac9fea1e92fc153ee7efc51afad3276bda8d7754a338b349d540bfb402cba0dfdc82498c217054efd8abd0f47a0c0bc963bbdf0dc938c91b17d9f2"
]);

$count = $client->count('bitcoin-prices', [
  'impressions' => [
    'interval' => 'daily',
    'timeframe' => 'this_30_days',
    'group_by' => 'keen.timestamp'
  ]
]);

print_r($count);
```

That project id and read key are from the keen io open data sets (good to test with).

Comment: The issue turned out to be the placement of the require statement; I moved it to the root directory and that resolved the problem. Additionally, use of the keen io open data set properties mentioned by @alex was helpful for verification.